# Android : start intent in setOnClickListener

Tags: android

I have a button with android:onClick="getGraph", therefore I create a function while its clicked, it retrieve user input, located at CheckByDate.java

```
public void getGraph (View view)
{
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textDay);
    textMonth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textMonth);
    textYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textYear);
    day = textDay.getText();
    month = textMonth.getText();
    year = textYear.getText();

    date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    Intent dategraphintent = new Intent(CheckByDate.this, DateGraph.class);
    dategraphintent.putExtra("date", date);
    startActivity(dategraphintent);
}
```

Then, in my DateGraph.java, I put something like this

```
public Intent getIntent(Context context)
{
    String date;
    date = getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
       .
       .
       .
       .   //This is where the date will interact with my web service, then receive 
       .   //an array set of values, and plot as a graph
       .
       .
}
```

But, i have no idea, when ever i clicked the button, it will forced to close and i got no idea at all, any ideas? i have tried using your method, or maybe i've done some stupid mistakes?? Please, i need your help....

Answer (score 2):

You defined your method

```
public Intent getthisIntent(Context context) {}
```

with one argument and you call it without param

```
getthisIntent();
```

You have to use

```
getthisIntent(YourActivity.this);
```

---

> then the button pass the values to the new intent, and start it
>   without having a new xxx.java file?

When you don't want to have another `Activity` so for what you want to use `Intent`? This make no sense. If you want to call new `Activity` when you click on `Button`, you should use following snippet:

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

---

> I have a button, and this button is going to get the values from
>   EditText, then using this value to start a new Intent

```
gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            day = textDay.getText().toString();
            month = textMonth.getText().toString();
            year = textYear.getText().toString();
            date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NewPlotActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("date", date);
            startActivity(i); // this will start new Activity where you plot a graph.
        }
```

Then, in your **NewPlotActivity** you can retrieve data with `getIntent().getStringExtra("date");`

**Note:** Don't forget to add `<activity android:name=".NewPlotActivity"></activity>` to your **Manifest.xml**

Comment: But the intent will be started only when the button is clicked, how can i link to the button then?

Comment: and when you want to call your method?? you already linked intent to your button, when you click on button, your method will be called.

Comment: check my updated anwer, you really don't need your method, see my snippet of code.

Comment: Please hawaii, please check through my code, and can you find any problem???? thanks a million....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12968/discussion-between-derek-and-hawaii-five-0)

Comment: first, you must use `toString()` method not only `getText()`, `getText()` from `EditText` returns `Editable` not `String` so you have to use `getText().toString()`. Then your method `public Intent getIntent(Context context) {}` is useless just put these two lines.without method. So in your DateGraph you should only have `String date;
date = getIntent().getStringExtra("date");`

Comment: I need the public Intent getIntent(Context context), because i have set all the functions in there, do i have other alternative?

Comment: oh man how i can to teach you basics? you really need to read some book about Android, because from your methods i'm really confused.

Comment: Ok, i will try to figure it out, anyway, thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are violating you method signature!!, call your method with a context object, use:

```
getthisIntent(YourActivity.this);
getthisIntent(getApplicationContext());
```